# Import of gitlab project fails in Codenvy

Tags: git, ide, gitlab, codenvy

I'm starting my first Codenvy project but have trouble [importing](https://codenvy.com/docs/user-guide/git-svn/index.html#svn-using-usernamepassword) a Gitlab project. I do the following:

> Workspace > Import Project > Subversion
>
> As URL I enter: https://gitlab.company-name.com/apps/app-name.

I'm quite certain the url is correct. However, I get the error message:

> Importing project app-name
>
> svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL ‘https://gitlab.company-name.com/apps/app-name/trunk’
>
> svn: E160013: ‘/apps/app-name/trunk’ path not found

The "default path" in codenvy is "/trunk". I've also tried it with this field empty but with the same result.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong when importing this project?

Answer (score 0):

I read on Codenvy documentation that oAuth connection is not enabled for GitLab yet.
This means that you have to clone your repo using ssh, but before doing that you need to setup your SSH keys correctly.

Read this doc for more info: https://codenvy.com/docs/user-guide/git-svn/index.html

I have been able to setup everything correctly, and now GitLsb connection doesn't fail on login but... I get s timeout error :)

Hope this helps.
S.

Edit:
From my side, I abandoned Codenvy because of this problem, and because it looks like the interesting Codenvy project died few years ago. The latest news on their website is dated 2017-05-25. Their Github repository looks dead too...

Comment: Codenvy became Eclipse Che. Please read this post: https://blog.codenvy.com/eclipse-che-6-is-coming-b43b2a43c7f2